# How to make the Add button in the same column as the Edit in the GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which only needs Edit and Add. Following is my aspx. My problem is, the Add button always shows under the column where the Delete Link Button should be (even I don't have one). How do I make the Add button in the same column as the Edit Link Button?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" 
        onpageindexchanging="OnPaging"  ShowFooter="true" 
        onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
        onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" >
        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>Vendor
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVendor" runat="server" 
                    AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="VendorChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="- Select a Vendor -" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("Vendor") %></ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            ...
            <asp:TemplateField>                          
                <FooterTemplate><asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" /></FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <asp:TemplateField>                          
     <ItemTemplate>   
      <table>
         <tr>
           <td>
              <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" CommandName="gAdd" CommandArgument='' runat="server" Text="Add" />   
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>
               <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" CommandName="gEdit" CommandArgument='' runat="server" Text="Edit" />
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

---

```
 protected void gr_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "gEdit")
            {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Put the `Edit` button in the `ItemTemplate` and the `Add` button in the `FooterTemplate`, like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>                          
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: No I don't want each row has a add button. I only want one add button at the bottom, but the same column as the Edit button.

Comment: I tried. The Edit buttons are disappear. Seems like you can't put commandfield in the itemtemplate

Comment: @GLP - you are correct, you cannot put `CommandField` controls inside of an `ItemTemplate`. I never use the `CommandField` controls so I apologize for missing that. I always create button controls and then wire them up through the `RowCommand` event or a single button click event handler in the case of footer or header buttons.